# Reading the data from USB device using libusb

Tags: c#, usb, libusb

```
[DllImport("winusb.dll", SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern Boolean WinUsb_ReadPipe(IntPtr InterfaceHandle, Byte PipeID, 
ref Byte Buffer, UInt32 BufferLength, ref UInt32 LengthTransferred, IntPtr Overlapped);
```

I am using the API to read async data from USB device, it works most of the time in 32 bit OS. But fails most of the time on 64 bit system.

Can anybody guide me if this is a problem with the API definition, firmware or something else?

Comment: I've had lots of challenges working with libusb on Windows. I might suggest using [more direct control of USB in C#/.NET](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/84338/making-usb-c-friendly/)...

Answer (score 0):

You show no code but the import. My immediate question is are you linking to the 64-bit version of `winusb.dll` on 64-bit systems? If your application is compiled for `Any CPU` in will run in 64-bit mode on 64-bit operating systems, and cannot P/Invoke into 32-bit libraries.

Comment: It compiled using AnyCPU option, some time i get LengthTransferred > 0 but some time it stuck on 0 length.